# Vagrant to use Puppet modules

Tags: vagrant, puppet

In order to install Puppet modules you need Puppet installed. To install Puppet you need a Puppet Master. I'm using Windows, Puppet Master does not install for Windows. What should I do? I just need to install a Puppet module so that I can use it when provisioning a vagrant instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to chose puppet architecture. [Master-agent](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/4.2/reference/architecture.html#the-agentmaster-architecture) architecture in puppet is recommended approach but you can also use [stand-alone](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/4.2/reference/architecture.html#the-stand-alone-architecture) architecture. So you **don't** have to install puppet master.

If you are using vagrant, you can create shell script, to provision guest machine, which will install and setup standalone puppet, or just [setup](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/puppet_apply.html) a puppet provisioner.
With puppet provisioner, remember to setup `module_path (Path, on the host, to the directory which contains Puppet modules, if any)`.

Last but not least, you **don't** need a puppet on host machine to "install" a puppet module. Just `download latest tar.gz` (e.g for [mysql](https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com/v3/files/puppetlabs-mysql-3.6.0.tar.gz) module) package with that module, and extract in to the directory pointed by `module_path`.

Comment: Awesome answer. Thank you. However, IMHO, I would not download the modules because then you have to worry about their dependencies, too.